# how rebuild lucene indexes over hibernate search jpa with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, lucene, hibernate-search

I have accidentally deleted my index directory, now i am trying to rebuild all indexes. 
I am using the hibernate search with JPA, lucene and MONGODB.

the following method is returning no results

```
    public void rebuildIndex()throws Exception{
    org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager fem = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

    org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fem.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = queryBuilder.all().createQuery();

    FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fem.createFullTextQuery(query, Person.class);

    //fullTextQuery.initializeObjectsWith(ObjectLookupMethod.SKIP, DatabaseRetrievalMethod.FIND_BY_ID);

    System.out.println(fullTextQuery.toString());

    List<Person> results = fullTextQuery.getResultList();

    fem.clear(); 
    System.out.println(results.size());
    for(Person p : results){
        fem.index( p );
        fem.flushToIndexes();
        fem.clear();
    }

    //fem.createIndexer().startAndWait();  
}
```

the method is returning no result. how should I get all data from mongoDb to rebuild index?

Comment: about your comment , you make me think that I am trying to retrieve all data from lucene index , right ? i think yes. how could I get all data from mongodb without consulting lucene indexes ?

Comment: You should clarify how you have Hibernate Search and MongoDB integrated. Is it using Hibernate OGM? In that case, it would have been enough to use the MassIndexer provided by Hibernate Search, it automates the index recontruction and is much more efficient than your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as hibernate search didn't work with criteria neither with JPQL and has his own JP-QL parser.
I couldn't create a findAll method to retrieve all objetcs
the only way was use a native mongoDb query:

```
org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager fem = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("mainBase");
    DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection("Persons");
    DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find();
    Collection<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    String id = "";
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        id = cursor.next().get("_id").toString();
        System.out.println(id);
        ids.add(id);
    }

    System.out.println(">"+ids.size());

    Person pes;
    for(String p : ids){
        pes = new Person();
        pes.setId(p);
        pes = find(pes);
        System.out.println("indexing: "+pes.getId());
        fem.index( pes );//index each element
        fem.flushToIndexes();//apply changes to indexes
        fem.clear();//free memory since the queue is processed
    }
```